# How to transplant ros to the ARM with ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, embedded

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install the ros on the ARM with ubuntu 11.10,  http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM,this web site provides the methods of  ubuntu 13.04, ubuntu 12.10 and ubuntu 12.04. while I need to transplant ros to the ARM with ubuntu 11.10. How can I do? Are there relevant tutorials or referencedata can refer. please help me.Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191626/how-to-transplant-ros-to-the-arm-with-ubuntu-11.10?/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 11.10 is no longer supported by Ubuntu, and isn't supported by ROS Hydro.

You can probably build ROS from source on your ARM board, or attempt to cross-compile it, but I *strongly* recommend upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Which version of ROS do you need, and which packages are you planning to use?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-09-01**:
Have adjust path to  cross-compilation ros?I just want to install ros on the ARM（ubuntu11.10 or linux 3.0.35）successful regardless of the version . I need to  transplant the packages which I write.In this case,if I must translpant the  roscore and other  related packages.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-02**:
You haven't answered either of my questions. Which version of ROS do you need, and which packages are you planning to use?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-02**:
I ask because it isn't possible to compile some packages (such as PCL) on the smaller ARM boards.

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-09-04**:
I need the groovy.And I want to install ros-common on the board.Than transplant my own packages.Is there adjust path to cross-compile roscore and rospackages.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-05**:
You can install Groovy from source on your board by following the [Groovy source installation](http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source). [meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros) provides support for cross-compiling ROS, but only supports ROS Hydro